# Passing an argument to a declared function

Tags: javascript, extjs6

I have the following function declaration

```
var exportStore = function (exportVar) {

    // Process export .cfc

    var params_JSON =  {
      <cfoutput>
      l_companyid: '#url.companyid#',
      l_start: '#l_start#',
      l_end: '#l_end#'
      </cfoutput>
    };

    if(exportVar == 'results') {
        var exportQuery = Ext.getCmp('query');
        var query = exportQuery.getValue();
        params_JSON.query = query;
    }

    <cfoutput>var url = 'some url parameters' + Ext.JSON.encode(params_JSON)';</cfoutput>

    //ajax call here returns link to export file

    // display export link
    var myForm = new Ext.form.Panel({
        title: 'Export File',
        width: 300,
        height: 200,
        floating: true,
        closable : true,
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            pack: 'center'
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            name: 'export_file',
            value: 'Click <a href="'+export file+'">here</a> to download file'
        }],
        buttons: [{
            margin: '0 10 10 0',
            text: 'Close',
            handler: function() {

                this.up('form').destroy();

            }
        }]
    });
```

I am attempting call this function from a button that has a drop down selection.

```
 {
    text: 'Export All',
    handler: exportStore
 },
 { 
    text: 'Export Search Results',
    handler: exportStore
 }
```

My question is can you pass a parameter to a function declared as a variable? I know I can just give both buttons their own handler, but that handler is going to contain quite a bit of code and im attempting to simplify... just wanted to know if a paramerter can be passed to exportStore in some form for example.....

```
{
        text: 'Export All',
        handler: [ 
        exportStore,
        extraParams: { exportVar: 'all' }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Ext.bind()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.html#method-bind) to achieve this like below:

```
var exportStore = function (exportVar) {
    // exportVar will have your 'all' or 'search' value as per the 
    // button clicked
    ...
}

// In definition
{
    text: 'Export All',
    handler: Ext.bind(exportStore, undefined, ['all'])
}, {
    text: 'Export Search Results',
    handler: Ext.bind(exportStore, undefined, ['search'])
}
```

You can refer [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1kri) for the usage.